# Binder not working, but the dashboard works locally

Tags: python, dashboard, voila

I try to use binder to publish a dashboard from the github repo:
https://github.com/ailjia/demo-test

On https://mybinder.org/, I used the URL: https://github.com/ailjia/demo-test
and path to the notebook file(option): voila/render/demo-final.ipynb

after launching, I got the error message:

```
"500 : Internal Server Error"
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a requirements.txt file with all the dependencies you used in your code.
This will make sure the build for the binder resources in sufficient